# The probability for the number of white balls in a bucket, after removing a ball and returning it k times.

Tags: probability

Given a bucket with 10 balls, which can be either white or black, the probability for the total number of white balls ($0..10$) is $\frac{1}{11}$.

What is the probability for 5 white balls, given that $k$ times a random ball was removed from the bucket and returned, and each time the ball was white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the joint probability that there are exactly $w$ white balls AND you observe White $k$ times in a row, $k≥1$, is $$(\frac 1{11})(\frac {w}{10})^k$$  Let $S$ denote the sum of these:  $$S=\sum_{w=1}^{10} (\frac 1{11})(\frac {w}{10})^k$$

The portion of that which is attributable to the case you have in mind, $w=5$ is $$\frac {(\frac 1{11})(\frac 5{10})^k}S$$

As a sanity check, note that, as $k\to \infty$ we have $S\to \frac 1{11}$  (as all the terms drop out except the one corresponding to $w=10$).  Thus we see that, for large $k$, the formula forces us to believe that $w=10$, as it should.

Comment: Also, summing this for all w gives 1 for all k from 1 to 10000.